# Is $\prod\limits_{p}{p^\frac{1}{p}}$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, prime-numbers, products

I am trying to prove or disprove if $\prod\limits_{p}{p^\frac{1}{p}}$ converges.

I have tested up to 400K and got the following value:
$$\prod_{p}{p^\frac{1}{p}}=0.26431187257195837519$$

while for natural numbers:
$$\prod_{n}{n^\frac{1}{n}}=\infty$$
divergent obviously.
If 
$$S(y)=\frac{1}{\pi}\arg(\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+iy))$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}|S(y_n)|=0.264$$
Running over the $\zeta(s)$ functions zeros.
according to

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.4358.pdf

Not sure if those are somehow related. But looks interesting.

---

Aster posting saw an obvious way to prove that the first sum divergent. Logarithm just shows this as the $\sum_{p}\frac{1}{p}$ divergent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Taking logarithms, $$\log \prod_p p^{1/p} = \sum_p \frac{\log p}{p}$$ and this sum diverges by Mertens' "first" theorem, or even just by comparison with $ \sum_p 1/p$.